# Swift / Firebase Storage - An unknown error occurred, please check the server response

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am suddenly getting the error

> "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response."

for any putData or getData function.

My code was working then suddenly stopped.
Firebase functions still work but Firebase Storage functions fail.

I have changed my firebase rules, but that didn't help.

Thanks in advance!

Here are my rules:

> rules_version = '2'; service cloud.firestore { match
> /databases/{database}/documents { match /{document=**} { allow read,
> write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 12, 22); } } } service
> firebase.storage{ match /b/{bucket}/o { match /{allPaths=**} { allow
> read, write: if true; } } }

-Rob Mathews

Comment: Did you "check the server response"?

Comment: I believe that is the server response.  When I try to perform a getData() the error returned also includes "Abandoning download due to status 412,"

Comment: Here are my rules:

Comment: rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2022, 12, 22);
     }
   }
  }
  service firebase.storage{
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}

Comment: Please try to print the complete response. Most of the time there is a message involved hinting on what could be wrong. Error `412` is allready hinting to a permission issue. Please add code to the question itself and format it properly. Code in comments is very hard to read.

Comment: Some clues might be available at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues?q=is%3Aissue+An+unknown+error+occurred%2C+please+check+the+server+response